# Как правильно построить архитектуру приложения

Tags: java, android, база-данных, архитектура

Условие. 
Есть некий сторонний источник, генерирующий случайные цифры. Каждую минуту генерируется от 1 до 10 пятизначных цифр. Источник отдаёт данные через json.

Задача.
Нужно парсить эти данные, где-то хранить. Также нужно где-то производить вычисления по неким формулам, с некоторыми из этого большого массива цифрами (диапазон цифр на выбор пользователя). Затем через приложение на Android пользователь может инициировать вычисление по той или иной формуле и получать результат на экран смартфона. Пользователей может быть много. Одновременно с данными могут работать до 1000 человек.

Вопрос.
Как лучше организовать "архитектуру" всего этого хозяйства? В частности:

- какую БД лучше использовать (Realm, SQLite и т.д.)?
- где производить вычисления? Я так понимаю, что лучше на сервере, на котором будет крутиться база, но может быть есть вариант/преимущества располагать вычисления непосредственно в Android приложении?
- на чём производить вычисления? Знаком на некотором уровне только с Java. Можно ли выкрутиться, не прибегая к другим языкам программирования?
- каким образом приложению забирать вычисления с сервера? Также по json?
- каким образом давать из приложения команды сервису на вычисление с выбранными пользователем значениями?
- если нет своего сервера, то где дёшево (бесплатно?) и сердито можно расположить БД и вычислительный сервис? Облако, хостинг?

Может быть это вообще как-то иначе реализуется и я думаю в не правильном направлении?

P.S. Простите, если вопросы глупые или слишком абстрактные, но я не программист, а лишь любитель самоучка, на счету которого пока только одно простецкое Android приложение без использования БД и сторонних источников.

Заранее спасибо за помощь!